# The name of start guide screen?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I've downloaded some apps, I saw start screen with guide, there were 3-4 screens, sliding between them and showing small guide to app. So how does it call and how to implement that? Is there any examples or tutorials?

Comment: They are called onboarding screens, and this question doesn't belong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OnBoarding Screens

It is called onboarding screen, You have to create each layout separately and code it. Again the screen should be shown only once when the app is launched for the very first time. If the user launches the app for the second time, he should directly go to the main screen. To achieve this, you must use `SharedPreferences` to store a boolean value indicating first time launch.

It's a broad answer and you must look [Source](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you can creat such screen with `ViewPager` and `Pager Indicator`. If you want some library or open-source reference [AppIntro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro) is a great resource to begin with. Just add `compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'` in your app level build.gradle file and refer this [example](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro/tree/master/example/src/main) for how to set your Fragments.